# Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode9

I'm using a beta of Xcode 9. I've archived my iOS Project and whenever I try to validate it, I get this error for every one of the targets in my app:

[image: Image of the error shown]

And I'm getting this error for every target like I said. The provisioning profile for each of the targets is an Xcode Managed Profile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should try two options:

1) In `Developer.Apple.com` create a distribution provisioning profile, download it, and select it.  Then re-archive your project and validate.  This should dismiss the error.

2) If option 1 doesn't work for you, click the `Export` button beside archive and save your `.app` file to your Desktop.  Then open `Application Loader` (In Xcode, click Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader). Enter your credentials, then upload the app using the .app file you generated and saved to your Desktop.

**Note:** Sometimes Xcode shows fake errors when validating and `Application Loader` will ignore those and allow you to upload a build successfully.

When `Application Loader` is finished, you should then be able to see your build in iTunesConnect after about 15-30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Sadly, neither of them wored. On 2, it wouldn't let me export because I am getting those errors...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you haven't created your distribution provisioning profile correctly and added it to your project.  Re-generate it and make sure that you don't have any typos

Comment: this must have a command line equivalent which really should be copy and pasteable from XCode screen ...  obviously the big shops have fully automated all this without needing to touch XCode when cutting a new iOS app file

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I wanted to make an enterprise build but I accidentally selected to upload build to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked on a simple second attempt with no changes or rebuild.